# "To be due" in the context of expecting a childbirth

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

One of the meanings of the adjective [due](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/due) is  "expected to give birth", another one is "expected according to timetable, promise etc."

The context:

> A: I saw Jane just the other day. Seems like you're going to become a
>   father soon.
>
> B: Yes, and it's going to be a boy!

What question may one ask (using "due)  about the approximate time (months or weeks) when the childbirth  is awaited?

Would it be about the baby boy expected to appear:

> When is he due?

Or about the mother expected to deliver the baby:

> When is she due?

What may be other most common questions (just a couple of them) to ask the father-to-be about the same thing.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212865/gone-vs-due-words-refering-to-pregnancy *When's the/your baby due?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of giving birth, 'due' can be used from the point of view of the child, or the mother. For example:

> When are you due (to give birth)?
>
> The baby is due in August
>
> My wife is due in three weeks.

With respect to the father, it's become more common for him to be included in the pregnancy process from start to finish, though in my experience, when speaking to the father, common practice is to discuss the father and mother as a collective, for example:

> When are you both due?
>
> When are you guys due?

Comment: As far as I know, it has **always** been common practice to include the father "*from the start*"! ;-)